# Can I bypass safari pop up blocker in javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

So I have a iframe that communicates to the parent in postMessage. The message passes a few objects but the issue is around the url that it passes. When the parent obtains the message and detects that there is a url associated with it, it fires it as a url.

This works in all browsers except Safari. My guess is because when it is treated as a click in the iFrame the parent is not tied to the click and Safari treats it as a non click. So when it tries to fire it gets blocked. When I turn of Safari's pop up blocker it works fine. However I am pretty sure that the default setting for the browser disables any pop ups.

The click that fires uses the window.open method along with a '_blank' target.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I would suggest you find another way to do this. While many users do use the default settings, you will find that popups are very frequently blocked by users of *all* browsers whether that is the default setting or not.

Comment: I suppose your right. Thanks for the advice!